# How to limit Datepicker to allow the user to select only quarter month of the year

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

The Datepicker must allow the user to only select the quater month in future. Dates in the past must not be allowed.

Eg.if we are in jan then in this case quater month should enabled(march) and jan and feb should disable.
if we are in mar then in this case quater month should enabled(march) and jan and feb should disable.
if we are in Apr then in this case quater month should enabled(jun) and jan,feb,mar,apr,may should disable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepickerOne').datepicker({
                format: "yyyy-mm",
                viewMode: "months",
                minViewMode: "months",
                autoclose: true,
                startDate: new Date(),
                endDate: '+2y',
            }).on("change", function () {
                $("#testDetailsForm").bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'formsubmit_date');
            })
        });
```

Comment: Could you formulate your question clearer?

Comment: @sam in date picker i need only current month and year(may be next 10 year) after that all month and year should be disabled.also pervious month should be disabled.

Comment: When you say current month, are dates before today allowed in the current month? For example, if today is 16th Jan, should 10th Jan be a enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the snippet, this code will allow you to only select a current month and after current month and a year. it won't allow you to go back in past

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepickerOne').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm",
        viewMode: "months",
        minViewMode: "months",
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate : '+10y'
    }).on("change", function () {
        $("#testDetailsForm").bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'formsubmit_date');
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type='text' name='datepickerOne' id='datepickerOne' class='datepickerOne form-control'>
```

Comment: Just have one dought,in month of feb(next month) is user will able to select jan?? as per your above code.

Comment: @sohan if you want to check for next month then you can use `new Date('03-01-2018')` instead of `new Date()` it will disabled Jan and Feb

Comment: its not about only jan and feb.i mean the past month should be disabled in calendar. suppose if i open my application in march that time jan and feb should be disabled in calendar. For that new Date() is enough right??

Comment: Yes, new Date is enough, It will work exactly what you are saying.

Comment: Sure Prateik,Thanks!!

Comment: @Prateil,can you tell me if i want to choose only quater month,how to do that.means if i choose the picker only jan and feb should disable

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `minDate: 0` ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepickerOne').datepicker({
                format: "yyyy-mm",
                viewMode: "months",
                minViewMode: "months",
                autoclose: true,
                minDate: 0
            }).on("change", function () {
                $("#testDetailsForm").bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'formsubmit_date');
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `minDate` and/or `maxDate` for the desired effect.

Follow the documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate).

Comment: i am not using date,only month and year i am using.also minDate/maxdate is not working for me,may be version issue.

Comment: You can always build a date object as needed given a month and year. `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`. Alternatively, `minDate` and `maxDate` also takes relative values in strings like `"+1y"`